# Scheduled execution at a certain point of a flow

Tags: spring-integration

I need a functionality which does the following:

- At a certain point of a flow the execution is paused till the specified time.
  (It's like parking / staging when all messages remain in a place till the specified time)
  So If you set 2016-04-20 11:12:00 for that time (ideally It's specified by cron expression) till that time everything is paused. (flow does not continue processing messages) If the specified time ellapses then a worflow continues the execution from the point where this 'staging' component resides.
- Is it possible to do that with Spring Integration?
- How should be implemented?

Comment: Let us know if `<delayer>` doesn't fit your requirements.

Comment: using delayer you cannot specify full date/time when execution can continue. What you can only do is to define a specified amount of time and messages will be delayed with that time.

I would like to specify the time by a cron expression like execution should continue execution of flow every sunday at 10:00.

I tried to find an appropriate taskExecutor for that functionality but I was not able to do that.

Comment: I also tried to use the aggregator component to achive it. I defined an aggregator and a release strategy which returned false. I also defined a message reaper with a cron expression.
aggregator properties:
send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
expire-groups-upon-completion="true" 
The problem with that design is that incomplete groups were also released when reaper fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `defaultDelay` for the `DelayHandler` can be calculated from the date value:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDelayer.handler")
private DelayHandler myDelayer;

...

Date nextDate = ...
myDelayer.setDefaultDelay(nextDate.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and use this code somewhere after start your application, e.g. `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

Or you can just place a desired `Date` to the message header and use `delay-expression`.

From other side you can just place your messages to the `QueueChannel` and use a desired `cron` from the `<poller>` on endpoint which should poll messages from that queue.

If you have so long `delay` time for those messages, you should consider to use `persistent` `MessageStore` on that `QueueChannel`.

Comment: It seems ok. You are always a great help!
I try to implement it.  I'll turn to you soon when It's completed.